# Remote access to mySQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have trouble connecting to my mySQL database remotely through Python.

I use the following to connect to mySQL:

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host='XXX.XXX.XXX.X',user='XXXX',password='XXXXXX',database='testdb')
```

But I get the following error:

```
2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '%HOST%:3306' (10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)
```

The server is running and when I run the same code on the computer I run the server from using `'localhost'`
    import mysql.connector
    cnx =

```
mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='XXXX',password='XXXXXX',database='testdb')
```

it works and I can modify the data in the database. I'm trying to connect it remotely from another computer though.

I've tried using `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO User@Host IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` but no result. I checked my firewall and allowed all incoming and outgoing connections through port 3306 which is used by default.

I'm new to mySQL and really have no clue what to do. I don't even know if I use the correct hostname :') I use the IP address of the computer I run the server from,I think that's right.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to GRANT ALL privilage to the user. You need to tell MYSQL that this user is allowed to login from a remote location.

In fact as you are allowing remote access through this user account now, you should make sure that it can access only the database(s) it needs to, and definitely cannot use `GRANT`

For example

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

Will allow this user to connect from any ip address. To be more secure you should try to be more specific and specify a individual ip address if you can

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'11.22.33.44' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

Remember, you are creating a new user account here because you already have a 
`myuser@localhost`

Either way you need to make sure that the password is a strong one, specially is you use the `%` any ip option

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. It just creates another user that cannot connect tothe database. I still get the same error

Comment: Then check the firewall is not blocking you

Comment: I made it so my firewall allows incoming and outgoing connections for port 3306 for all IP's.